# Can STEP files contain polygon data? How do I get a smoother mesh out of a STEP file?

Tags: 3d, mesh, polygon, nurbs, cad

I am trying to work with a .STEP file I have received. Upon opening it in CAD Assistant, I find
its surface as jagged lines, like a low poly model. When I export it as OBJ from there, the edges and vertices are just the same.

[image: Screenshot from CAD Assisstant]
[image: File exported as OBJ and imported in blender]

I want to use this model to create renderings. Although I can recreate this simple surface in Blender, this is a problem I frequently encounter with STEP files.

I assumed STEP files only contain NURBS data. So is this a limitation on my end (CAD Assisstant), or the original source of this file? Thank you.